# Do I have to clone() an array of floats?

Tags: java, arrays

If I've got `float[] a = {1,2,3};`, can I copy it using only `float[] b = a;` to obtain a deep copy? How do I know when I need to use `a.clone()`?

To clarify: I want to be able to change `a` (e.g. `a[0]=4;`) without affecting `b`.

Comment: `float[] b = a;` means that both `b` and `a` are references to the same `float[]` and changes done through b are of course seen through a and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant to ask if I can to that to obtain a deep copy.

Comment: When you assign a reference, you are only copying the reference. IMHO This is because Java is an OO language, not a functional language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just making `float[] b = a;` is not enough because then the array object will be shared between the 2 references `a` and `b`.

**But because you have an array of primitive types** is enough to use `float[] b = a.clone()`. The clone in this case will make a deep copy and will duplicate the array object including the primitive values inside.

If you had an array of some reference type you would need to clone the array and than iterate and clone every object to get a deep copy.

Answer (score 4):

Shallow copying means only making the new reference to point to the memory location of the old array, while deep copying means allocating a new memory location and copying the contents of the first array to other.

Use deep copy only when you are afraid that someone will nullify/delete the first array. In that case your second array will also be pointing to non existent memory or null. If you have a requirement to save the contents in the second array then go for deep copy otherwise use shallow copy.

Read more about shallow and deep copy here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy

This is how you can make shallow or deep copy of your array:

**Shallow copy**

```
float[] b = a;
```

**Deep copy**

```
float[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

`float[] b = a;` means you are assigning the reference of the Array object held by variable `a` to variable `b`.

Use [Arrays.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28float%5b%5d,int%29) or [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to clone an array in Java. Also look at the [micro-benchmarking](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue124.html).

Comment: `copyOf` requires so many unnecessary arguments. Why not `clone`?

Comment: @Andreas `clone` is indeed easier to use when you just want to copy a whole array and the three methods (clone, arrayCopy and copyOf) are similar performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know when I need to use a.clone()?

Whenever you write `a = b` in Java where `a` and `b` are not primitives (i.e. boolean, char, byte, int, long, float, double), you are copying a reference.

In your example, when writing `float[] a = {1,2,3};` then `float[] b = a;`, you only create one array, but have two variables "pointing" to it. So any change made to the array will be reflected on `a` and `b`.

To get a deep copy of your array and achieve your goal, simply clone it:

```
float[] b = a.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

no you need to do it for example like:

```
float[] b = (float[])a.clone();
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast it?

Comment: @Andreas It'll be implicitly cast, no need to explicit cast here.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that you can clone primitives, but if you had to you could always create a new array and a loop to copy all the values of one into the other.

Comment: Array of primitives is not a primitive , it is an object.